# Use of internationalized URL's

Tags: content-manager

Some organizations use localized URL's and some languages have non-standard characters (other than a-z), for example:

`http://example.com/lær-mer/vanlige-spørsmål-om-sport`

Tridion does not allow some of these characters in the standard configuration, and I am aware this behavior can be changed in the `cm_xml_usr.xsd` file.

Is there any concern to update the directory and filepath regex to allow for these non-standard characters? And what would this regex look like?

Answer (score 3):

In the (far) past, we have observed that not all web servers/browser deal equally well with non-ASCII characters in paths/URLs.
Note that Tridion does not support IRIs (internationalized URIs), so if you have non-ASCII characters in your path, these will be UTF-8 URL encoded (resulting in quite unreadable URLs). Most browsers will present the URL unencoded to the user (and then it looks fine again).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered solving this outside of the CMS with URL Rewrites.

- .NET/IIS > URL [Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
- Java/Unix > [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

You could still manage the rewrite rules within the CMS with a content modeled solution if need be.

Be sure also that the presentation file system allows such characters in the folder name.